# Evitar que una función en onkeyup se ejecute dos veces en inputs diferentes

Tags: javascript

amigas y amigos..

tengo el siguiente codigo en el que mediante unos inputs podemos cambiar el sentido de la oración utilizando nuevos verbos, adverbios y demas..

el tema es que cuando ingreso algo en un campo, los otros que tienen el mismo nombre de funcion en el onkeyup se borran, dejandome el parrafo vacio en esos espacios hasta que ingrese otras palabras en esos inputs..

mi pregunta es como puedo ejecutar la funcion si que pase a llevar a los otros inputs que tienen el mismo nombre de funcion en su onkeyup..

```
        <div class="container" style="width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2>FRASE: </h2>

    <p style="font-size:2em"> <span id="sustantivo">Juan</span> se <span id="verbo_sentia">sentía</span> <span
            id="calificativo_solo"> solo</span>, <span id="verbo_volvia">
            volvía</span> a su departamento, y el
        <span id="cambia_silencio">silencio </span> era el <span id="calificativo_unico">único </span> que lo <span
            id="verbo_esperaba">esperaba</span>.
        Juan <span id="verbo_estaba_1">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_triste">triste</span> , Juan <span
            id="verbo_estaba_2">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_solo2">solo</span> , muy <span
            id="calificativo_solo3">solo</span>. Y
        Juan <span id="verbo_tuvo">tuvo</span> una <span id="calificativo_brillante">brillante</span>
        idea:</p>

    <form id="frase" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Cambie su frase:</legend>
            <p>* Presione enter al completar cada campo</p>
            <!-- Cambia el sustantivo propio-->
            <label for="adjetivo">Cambia el Sustantivo propio:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_sustantivo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo volvía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo(volvía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_volvia" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo sentía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Sentía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_sentia" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo esperaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Esperaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_esperaba" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba1" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba 2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (juan estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba2" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo tuvo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Tuvo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_tuvo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 2):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo2" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo3-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 3):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo3" onkeyup=" FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo triste-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Triste):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_triste" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo brillante-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Brillante):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_brillante" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo unico-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Único):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_unico" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Eligue el sustantivo de silencio-->
            <label for="silencio">Seleccione un sustantivo para (silencio):</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="disimulo">
            <label for="disimulo"> disimulo</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="misterio">
            <label for="misterio"> misterio</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="discrecion">
            <label for="discrecion"> discreción</label><br>


            <!-- Eligue el sustantivo de idea-->
            <label for="silencio">Seleccione un sustantivo para (idea):</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="disimulo">
            <label for="disimulo"> disimulo</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="misterio">
            <label for="misterio"> misterio</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="discrecion">
            <label for="discrecion"> discreción</label><br>




        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>

</div>

<script>
    function FunctionCambiar() {


        // cambia sustantivo propio
        var sustantivo = document.getElementById("ingresa_sustantivo").value;
        document.getElementById("sustantivo").textContent = sustantivo;
        document.getElementById("sustantivo").style.background = "#d1f0ff";


        // cambia verbo volvia
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_volvia").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo sentia
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_sentia").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo esperaba
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_esperaba").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo estaba 1
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba1").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo estaba 2
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba2").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo tuvo
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_tuvo").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo2
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo2").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").style.background = "#e9d4ff";

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo3
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo3").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos triste
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_triste").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").style.background = "#e9d4ff";

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos brillante
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_brillante").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos único
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_unico").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").style.background = "#e9d4ff";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Verifica que la variable no esté vacía antes de hacer el cambio: `if(valor.trim() != '') { /* asignar valor y aplicar estilo */}`

Comment: cuando te refieres a valor.trim es para capturar el id del formulario completo o tengo que hacer la comprobación dentro de cada una de las variables ?

Comment: `var verbo = document...(); if(verbo.trim() != '') { ... }`

Comment: no funciono :(  

 var sustantivo = document.getElementById("ingresa_sustantivo").value;
            if (sustantivo.trim() != '') {
                document.getElementById("sustantivo").textContent = sustantivo;
                document.getElementById("sustantivo").style.background = "#d1f0ff";
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es analizar el valor de cada variable y hacer el cambio correspondiente solo si no está vacía. Se usa trim para eliminar espacios que pudiera haber al inicio o al final de la cadena.

```js
    function FunctionCambiar() {
        // cambia sustantivo propio
        var sustantivo = document.getElementById("ingresa_sustantivo").value;
        if(sustantivo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("sustantivo").textContent = sustantivo;
            document.getElementById("sustantivo").style.background = "#d1f0ff";
        }


        // cambia verbo volvia
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_volvia").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia verbo sentia
        verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_sentia").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia verbo esperaba
        verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_esperaba").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia verbo estaba 1
        verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba1").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia verbo estaba 2
        verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba2").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia verbo tuvo
        verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_tuvo").value;
        if(verbo.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").textContent = verbo;
            document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").style.background = "#ebffdb";
        }


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo2
        calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo2").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo3
        calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo3").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos triste
        calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_triste").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos brillante
        calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_brillante").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos único
        calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_unico").value;
        if(calificativos.trim() != '') {
            document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").textContent = calificativos;
            document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").style.background = "#e9d4ff";
        }

    }
```

```html
        <div class="container" style="width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2>FRASE: </h2>

    <p style="font-size:2em"> <span id="sustantivo">Juan</span> se <span id="verbo_sentia">sentía</span> <span
            id="calificativo_solo"> solo</span>, <span id="verbo_volvia">
            volvía</span> a su departamento, y el
        <span id="cambia_silencio">silencio </span> era el <span id="calificativo_unico">único </span> que lo <span
            id="verbo_esperaba">esperaba</span>.
        Juan <span id="verbo_estaba_1">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_triste">triste</span> , Juan <span
            id="verbo_estaba_2">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_solo2">solo</span> , muy <span
            id="calificativo_solo3">solo</span>. Y
        Juan <span id="verbo_tuvo">tuvo</span> una <span id="calificativo_brillante">brillante</span>
        idea:</p>

    <form id="frase" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Cambie su frase:</legend>
            <p>* Presione enter al completar cada campo</p>
            <!-- Cambia el sustantivo propio-->
            <label for="adjetivo">Cambia el Sustantivo propio:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_sustantivo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo volvía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo(volvía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_volvia" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo sentía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Sentía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_sentia" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo esperaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Esperaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_esperaba" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba1" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba 2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (juan estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba2" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo tuvo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Tuvo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_tuvo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 2):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo2" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo3-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 3):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo3" onkeyup=" FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo triste-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Triste):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_triste" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo brillante-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Brillante):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_brillante" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo unico-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Único):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_unico" onkeyup="FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Eligue el sustantivo de silencio-->
            <label for="silencio">Seleccione un sustantivo para (silencio):</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="disimulo">
            <label for="disimulo"> disimulo</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="misterio">
            <label for="misterio"> misterio</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="discrecion">
            <label for="discrecion"> discreción</label><br>


            <!-- Eligue el sustantivo de idea-->
            <label for="silencio">Seleccione un sustantivo para (idea):</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="disimulo">
            <label for="disimulo"> disimulo</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="misterio">
            <label for="misterio"> misterio</label><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="discrecion">
            <label for="discrecion"> discreción</label><br>




        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>

</div>
```